# Code Golf: Letter-Ception

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

**The Challenge:**

For an input of one letter X (upper or lower case from A to Z) and one digit N (0-9) print the corresponding letter X made of N * X.

The letter has to be from this list:

```
 AAA      BBBB       CCCC     DDDD      EEEEE     FFFFF      GGG      H   H
A   A     B   B     C         D   D     E         F         G         H   H
AAAAA     BBBB      C         D   D     EEEE      FFFF      G  GG     HHHHH
A   A     B   B     C         D   D     E         F         G   G     H   H
A   A     BBBB       CCCC     DDDD      EEEEE     F          GGG      H   H


IIIII         J     K   K     L         M   M     N   N      OOO 
  I           J     K  K      L         MM MM     NN  N     O   O
  I           J     KKK       L         M M M     N N N     O   O
  I       J   J     K  K      L         M   M     N  NN     O   O
IIIII      JJJ      K   K     LLLLL     M   M     N   N      OOO 


PPPP       QQQ      RRRR       SSSS     TTTTT     U   U     V   V     W   W
P   P     Q   Q     R   R     S           T       U   U     V   V     W   W
PPPP      Q   Q     RRRR       SSS        T       U   U     V   V     W   W
P         Q  QQ     R  R          S       T       U   U      V V      W W W
P          QQQQ     R   R     SSSS        T        UUU        V        W W 


X   X     Y   Y     ZZZZZ
 X X       Y Y         Z 
  X         Y         Z  
 X X        Y        Z   
X   X       Y       ZZZZZ
```

**Examples:**

input: a 1

output:

```
 AAA
A   A
AAAAA
A   A
A   A
```

---

input: A 0

output: `A`

---

input: A 2

output:

```
      AAA  AAA  AAA
     A   AA   AA   A
     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
     A   AA   AA   A
     A   AA   AA   A
 AAA                 AAA
A   A               A   A
AAAAA               AAAAA
A   A               A   A
A   A               A   A
 AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA
A   AA   AA   AA   AA   A
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
A   AA   AA   AA   AA   A
A   AA   AA   AA   AA   A
 AAA                 AAA
A   A               A   A
AAAAA               AAAAA
A   A               A   A
A   A               A   A
 AAA                 AAA
A   A               A   A
AAAAA               AAAAA
A   A               A   A
A   A               A   A
```

---

input: A -1

output: *what ever: it doesn't matter*

---

**Additional Rules:**

- The input parameters can be separated by what ever character you
     want.
- Each letter must use the capital of itself as the ascii-character to draw it.
- Trailing spaces, new lines etc. are allowed
- Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes the digit string as an argument. The output should be printed normally.
- Stdout / Stderr doesn't matter, just pick one. If stuff gots printed on the other doesn't matter either.
- Possible output formats can be printed to STDOUT, returned as a list of strings, returned as a character matrix, etc. as long as the result can simply be printed using the languages default print method.*

*: like the function f(a,1) returns the string and one can simply say print(f(a,1)) dont make the print() call part of the answer. (This was pointed out by Kevin Cruijssen and  Arnauld).

**Winning:**

This is code-golf, lowest byte-count wins. Have fun!

---

**Edit**: this question seems *very identical* to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/create-an-h-from-smaller-hs) however I would say it is not, as it should not only work for H but for each letter from the alphabet.. Guess you decide rather or not it is a duplicate.

Comment: Does output have to be printed or can it be a return value like a string array?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder does it make sense if I say as long as it is properly formatted its OK ?

Comment: [*Very* closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157664/42963).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork you are right, I didn't see that, should I delete it ?

Comment: You'd need to define what properly formatted means, just having all the spaces and new lines in the array, a 2d array with spaces in cells etc. Also your A 2 example has leading spaces, is that intentional?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Just having all the spaces and new lines is enough and the leading spaces are not intentional, I will go fix this.

Comment: I don't think they are duplicates -- needing to account for a different letter each run and your letters are different than the `H` from the linked question -- but they are close enough that I wanted to call it out as it's likely there can be some code or algorithm re-use between the two.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157664/52210), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/160012/52210), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54453/52210), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117711/52210). PS: @NicolasBrauer related means it can contain tips/similarities on how to do this challenge, it's not necessarily a duplicate. Although the first one is pretty similar for the letter H. Oh, and since no one said it yet: welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thank you very much for the explanation and the welcome :D

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80940/194). [Possibly the closest existing question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44913/194).

Comment: [Also *somewhat* related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166838/58974). Welcome to PPCG; nice first challenge. A couple more test cases using different letters wouldn't hurt, though. I'd also suggest against requiring us to handle the special case of `N=0` - it doesn't (seem to me) to add anything to the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy thank you :) So you suggest making the output for all `N<=0` to _what ever: it doesn't matter_  ?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. It's always good to see someone actually respond to questions that are asked about their challenge and take hints on board. Respect. You may want to try the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time (just in case you didn't know about it).

Comment: @ElPedro Thank you! I did not know about the sandbox yet, thank you very much I will take a closer look at it!

Comment: Nice first challenge! However, your question currently suggests that we may only _print_ the result. The default rule is that functions are allowed to just return it. Generally speaking, I/O formats are very flexible. You may want to have a look at [this post in meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/58563) which explains why.

Comment: @Arnauld as it is about ASCII art I would say to _print_ the result is somewhat crucial to the task, but I guess if your code returns the result and the returned string could simply be printed using the languages default print method (like your function f(a,1) return the string and I can just say print(f(a,1)) the print() call has not to be part of the answer code. If this is somewhat understandable and you agree I may add this to the challenge description.

Comment: @NicolasBrauer That's indeed how it's usually done. For this challenge for example, some possible output formats could be indeed printed to STDOUT, returned as a list of strings, returned as a character matrix, etc. In the footer of [Try it online]-links we can add the print, since that part could be pretty verbose and doesn't add much to the challenge itself (which is also why functions are allowed instead of full programs, since in some languages (i.e. Java), a function can be halve the byte-count of a full program, and does exactly the same.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I slightly updated the question, please tell me if its understandable the way I wrote it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 259 bytes

```r
function(K,N,`!`=utf8ToInt){if(N)for(i in 1:N)T=T%x%(sapply(!"			




",intToBits)[1:5,5*(-64+!K)-4:0]>0)
write(c(" ",K)[T+1],1,5^N,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBagIxECVloTWH3R2KByls1oCY1Ahu0VJsLVTwUCx7aAM9qEURAwHJikbaIn77NhF6aBlmMu/lvXeYbanSh3ap9mZpdWHYWORiXp8P9lbdyeLZWH7QiuVcFVumU23SrJ9zOZCNrwbbLTab9Ter0xAIQOQrQQglEThEUISIHyhENQjBS0gQBCSOYwcr5xVwWkTgqurkl9WTBkKX4RwANZcSVSBBYRx5WwD@1zX2WxW7F3vgAi@CM0KFNlYWQ213fJL1e6J3zdq33VZ9zNvdfmf22OH4c6vtii0ZTakY84lsZTORid5HLgSl/FgqRt@p6PD75cKy5tQ0OXbUExXZP2pIxc0fyt1mvbLWn@dlJOXo9Y0fcJqqE/trp1NDOT6WPw)

> ***Disclaimer :***
>   *this solution has been obtained by taking [@Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177484/41725) and replacing the matrix compression with another approach very very similar to the one used in [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177398/41725), so first of all go upvote them* :)

The idea is the following :

Given this `5 x 26*5` matrix of `0/1` :

```r
(1 replaced by '#', 0 replaced by '.' and '|' added for readability)

.####|#####|.###.|#####|#####|#####|.###.|#####|#...#|...#.|#####|#####|#####|
#.#..|#.#.#|#...#|#...#|#.#.#|#.#..|#...#|..#..|#...#|....#|..#..|....#|.#...|
#.#..|#.#.#|#...#|#...#|#.#.#|#.#..|#...#|..#..|#####|....#|..#..|....#|..#..|
#.#..|#.#.#|#...#|#...#|#.#.#|#.#..|#.#.#|..#..|#...#|....#|.#.#.|....#|.#...|
.####|.#.#.|#...#|.###.|#...#|#....|..##.|#####|#...#|####.|#...#|....#|#####| ...
  ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^   
  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |   
  A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J     K     L     M
```

each column is considered as binary number and converted to an integer. These integer are then converted to unprintable ASCII in the range 1...31 :

e.g. for the columns of `"B"` the final string will be `"\017\021\017\021\017"` (unprintable chars written in octal representation):

```r
#####                   ####.     11110          15            '\017'
#.#.#                   #...#     10001          17            '\021'
#.#.#      ------->     ####. --> 11110  ------> 15   ------>  '\017'
#.#.#                   #...#     10001          17            '\021'
.#.#.                   ####.     11110          15            '\017'

          (transposed                  bin to int   int to ASCII
         for reability)
```

Hence, given the final string of `5*26 = 130` characters, we convert that string back to the matrix of `0/1` using :

```r
sapply(utf8ToInt(STRING),intToBits)
```

then we simply subsect the matrix selecting only the first 5 rows (intToBits returns 32 bits) and only the columns corresponding to the letter passed as input and finally we apply kronecker as explained in [@Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177484/41725).

Comment: you can also use unprintables to shave off the `-48` piece, and use `!` in place of `U`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##XVDBagIxECVloTWH3R2KByls1oCY1Ahu0VJsLVTwUCx7aAM9qEURAwHJikbaIn77NhF6aBlmMu/lvXeYbanSh3ap9mZpdWHYWORiXp8P9lbdyeLZWH7QiuVcFVumU23SrJ9zOZCNrwbbLTab9Ter0xAIQOQrQQglEThEUISIHyhENQjBS0gQBCSOYwcr5xVwWkTgqurkl9WTBkKX4RwANZcSVSBBYRx5WwD@1zX2WxW7F3vgAi@CM0KFNlYWQ213fJL1e6J3zdq33VZ9zNvdfmf22OH4c6vtii0ZTakY84lsZTORid5HLgSl/FgqRt@p6PD75cKy5tQ0OXbUExXZP2pIxc0fyt1mvbLWn@dlJOXo9Y0fcJqqE/trp1NDOT6WPw)

Comment: @Giuseppe : great ! I made the answer a community wiki since it's the result of a collaboration :) Feel free to edit my poor english :D

Comment: I just noticed that this one is the answer with the lowest byte-count, so let me make this the accepted and thus winning answer 

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES8), 281 bytes

Takes input as `(letter)(N)`. Returns a string.

```javascript
c=>n=>(g=y=>y--?''.padEnd(w).replace(/./g,(_,x)=>(h=d=>~~(d/=5)?(P=parseInt)('hhvhefhfhfu111ufhhhfv1f1v11f1vehp1ehhvhhv444vehgggh979hv1111hhlrhhpljhehhhe11fhfuphheh9fhffge1u4444vehhhh4ahhhalhhhha4ah444ahv248v'[y/d%5+5*P(c,36)-50|0],36)>>x/d%5&1?h(d):' ':c)(w))+`
`+g(y):'')(w=5**n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NS8NAEIbv/RVedHfS5mNroqawKSoevPUuYpfsx1hCsiTt2oD0r8cJ3nQHhnee952BPaighrr/9Me47bSZrJxqWbWy4k6OshrjeMtY4pV@aTX/gqQ3vlG14WmSuhX/WJ2Boii1rC4XrlNZwJbvpFf9YF7bI3CGGNBYpDoJIU4WEW0QVgQxN4NemDmCIc9zGp1zWN6XSLYQiE2P6JsDUgYNbdAVTwpLUtYZccp/1@jlippqZqlIE1cY1vlDYG9jqq@LZRHteL26vYO4yL6z91lV1Xm2bsQWuYYNu2KbGuibsNwv9kvHR2KMgCyiqIWp7tqha0zSdI5bzh7JygAWf/ATYfEfPxNeA0w/)

### How?

#### Font encoding

The letters are \$5\times5\$, which means that each row can be encoded as a 5-digit binary value, i.e. \$0\$ to \$31\$ in decimal. These values can conveniently be stored as a single digit in Base36.

The pattern that is stored is mirrored both horizontally and vertically.

*Example for 'F':*

```
#####     ....#     00001      1     '1'
#....     ....#     00001      1     '1'
####. --> .#### --> 01111 --> 15 --> 'f' --> '11f1v'
#....     ....#     00001      1     '1'
#....     #####     11111     31     'v'
```

The whole font is stored as a single string of \$26\times5 = 130\$ characters.

To test the 'pixel' at \$(x,y)\$ for the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ letter, we do:

```javascript
parseInt('hhvhefhfh...'[y + 5 * n], 36) >> x & 1
```

#### Main algorithm

Given \$n\$, we define \$w=5^n\$, which is the width of the final output.

For \$0\le x<w\$ and \$0\le y<w\$, we want to know if the output pixel at \$(x,y)\$ is set or not. We use the recursive function \$h\$, which tests the letter pixel located at:

$$\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{5^k}\right\rfloor\bmod 5,\left\lfloor\frac{y}{5^k}\right\rfloor\bmod 5\right)$$

for all \$k\$ in \$[0 \dots n-1]\$.

The function returns a space as soon as a blank pixel is detected at some depth, or the character corresponding to the input letter if all iterations are successful.

Comment: It works really good, congratulations! Can you try to explain the code a bit please ?

Comment: Why has the pattern that is stored to be mirrored both horizontally and vertically? would it take more bytes to not mirror it at all for storing ? And tyvm for the explanation \*.\*

Comment: @NicolasBrauer It's mirrored vertically because \$y\$ is decreasing from \$w-1\$ to \$0\$. And it's mirrored horizontally because the leftmost 'pixel' is mapped to the _least_ significant bit (i.e. on the right of the number it's mapped to). The decoding would be a bit longer if it was not mirrored at all.

Comment: (Although I think we could drop the vertical mirror at no cost.)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 348 bytes

```r
function(K,N){if(N)for(i in 1:N)T=T%x%matrix(c(15269425,32045630,16269839,32032318,33061407,33061392,15224366,18415153,32641183,1082926,18444881,17318431,18732593,18667121,15255086,32045584,15255151,32045649,16267326,32641156,18400814,18400580,18400938,18157905,18157700,32575775)[utf8ToInt(K)-64]%/%2^(24:0)%%2,5,5)
write(c(" ",K)[T+1],1,5^N,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBasMwDIbvfYpgCLWZyiTbsuVuO2y3UcgpsEPXQgkL5LAUQsoKY8@euU0PY7ePz/p/CQ9TWzyupvbUN2N37PUGKvPdtboy7XHQXdH1Ba0rUz/V5bn8PIxDd9aNJrYhecvgLHoODoFCNuLSxTjrSMA5DOQxzuCShZyy3oUAJJ6Y2OXh4InEAaHYZK8v3osQUMwd3mWQ6CynPCIhRLJ0qWFGCfNyFj@b3Hg7x6frOTkXbhv42owo5GdgwRmSkwzEMSHPEBFzimMmNtvT2Ep9fO1HvTGr4HflfWn32vo1mrK0wMBm8TV040f@FVUo2JhtfUc7IOB9BaCU@Zlard4UoHloDqNevvdLs8jqWQH9Uy8K7B81/QI)

Uses an encoding nearly identical to [Ouros'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177397/67312); however, it does not reverse the bits, instead opting to use them directly.

It then creates a 5x5 matrix of bits and builds the [Kronecker Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) matrix to generate the necessary pattern, writing the results to stdout.

Comment: This is a great use of Kronecker !

Comment: [272 using another compression method](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH3vryiBYu4WmSlx0262vRt9kI4Etsoe/AARAwWp4iJziL@93ggbbISb3HNyziG5@9aGT93WHpqVq7cNL4UWk9HB2UG1HTcOTrXlGux2z@uwbkKZaKhGVXSMPpe73eabTzhL0SBmfmkppc6QkJGZNH6TqRxjil5ilFImz3OCw4chklYaLAuSvxRXDaaUQQ7EMaVkQ9QyzTNvU@hvqRLfFQmdiQcUOFCxYdBVA/H7hyMco7soXvBeoiCKYpiK/g29tITuvSJp0psHX/varfmKs5CJEqbVrZwLKfoLLQRjcG4tZx9M9OBxtXS8M2s6EBCFTMh/1DMT8R@KRrVZO@en9VpUVfH2DqcgDO2V/bGzWcMgOLcX "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll the heart of this challenge is the compression method (from a code-golf perspective anyway). Why don't you post it as an answer so you can explain it, too?

Answer (score 5):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>436</s> 372 bytes

Significantly shorter with new IO format.

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
t=transpose
f=flatten
$0c=[[c]]
$n c=f[t(f[t($(n-1)if(isOdd({#18415150,16301615,31491134,16303663,32554047,1096767,15262766,18415153,32641183,15254032,18128177,32539681,18405233,18667121,15255086,1097263,32294446,18136623,16267326,4329631,15255089,4539953,11191857,18157905,4329809,32575775}.[toInt(max'A'c)-65]>>p))c' ')\\p<-[i..i+4]])\\i<-[0,5..20]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVHdS8MwEH/fXxFw0BbTksvHpQE7GOjDYCDiY@1D13UjsGZjjaKI/7o1qeJDuPzufh9w15361k3Def966snQWjfZ4XK@evLs9w/ujYaytbuFr/y1dePlPPaLQ3U4td73brFkXVXXXdMslo501aH2aXzL1OWQ2UNqx8f9Pv28gVKCAsUooGCAoKgAaQCEnDsCUVDBlZJMagrMoMZQFUeuEemfOlJQApQijgJX8DACXoLWUS0MlhDJTHEROCWiBg4zWbESo7HmcxI3UspoDCGaBy5y1MGdSsENin@NoTLYmhANAAZKpaNGacPUTC2Ziclaaa2@itqfN86nQ/uerJMuy1E1q9Uly7qEJNnLy@Uur21R2FvZNAHaABlVRcFZ00zPvg07r0jc7Mm6fiQpWRJOkqeEZNN3F/rHcco32@n@w7WD7X7B73Xm7/p6DPea8t0P)

Compresses the letter patterns into the bits of integer literals to save ~700 bytes. For example, `A`:

1. Flatten `[[' AAA '],['A   A'],['AAAAA'],['A   A'],['A   A']]`
2. Reverse `[' AAA A   AAAAAAA   AA   A']`
3. Turn `['A   AA   AAAAAAA   A AAA ']` into binary (`'A' = 1, ' ' = 0`)
4. Turn `0b1000110001111111000101110` into decimal
5. Get `18415150`